# Scala to Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, dstream

I am trying to perform a join between a Dstream and a static RDD.

**PySpark**

```
  #Create static data
    ip_classification_rdd = sc.parallelize([('log_name','enrichment_success')])
    #Broadcast it to all nodes
    ip_classification_rdd_broadcast = sc.broadcast(ip_classification_rdd)
    #Join stream with static dataset on field log_name      
    joinedStream = kafkaStream.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(ip_classification_rdd[log_name]))
```

I get this exception:
"It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an "

**Scala**

However, someone has the same requirement here: [How to join a DStream with a non-stream file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032659/how-to-join-a-dstream-with-a-non-stream-file)

And this was the solution:

```
val vdpJoinedGeo = goodIPsFltrBI.flatMap{ip => geoDataBC.value.get(ip).map(data=> (ip,data)}
```

What is the equivalent for this in Pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes are required in your code:

- You can not broadcast an `RDD`: instead do it on the underlying "data":
- You then obtain the broadcast variable inside the closure using the `value()` method

Here is an approximation of what your updated code might look like:

```
 #Create static data
    data = [('log_name','enrichment_success')])
    #Broadcast it to all nodes
    ip_classification_broadcast = sc.broadcast(data)
    #Join stream with static dataset on field log_name      
    joinedStream = kafkaStream.transform(lambda rdd:  \
        rdd.join(ip_classification_broadcast.value().get[1]))
```

Comment: Snippet of the error log:
rdd.join(ip_classification_broadcast.value().get()[log_name]))
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Looks like `value` is an attribute not a method - so i've updated the code above: try `.get[log_name]` instead of `get()[log_name]`.  You will need to tweak these details a bit since I don't have your code and  test set up.

Comment: To debug, i have run the content of the join function.
`ip_classification_broadcast.value().get[log_name]`  results in: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`
This: `ip_classification_broadcast.value[0]` results in: `('log_name', 'enrichment_success')`
How ever when I run the spark-submit, this is the error:
`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mapValues'`

Comment: Ah - that means we're close!  You might need to restructure the `data` so that it is a `dict` not a `tuple`. But before doing that - by using the current `tuple`: the following should compile and give you `enrichment_success` as the output:  `ip_classification_broadcast.value().get[1]` . Notice the `[1]` that accesses the second element of the `tuple`. Later on you'll want to be able to access via the key `log_name`: that will require restructuring.

Comment: CASE 1:
`ip_classification_broadcast = sc.broadcast(data)
joinedStream = kafkaStream.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(ip_classification_broadcast.value[0]))`

ERROR
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mapValues'

Comment: CASE2:
`ip_classification_broadcast = sc.broadcast(data)
joinedStream = kafkaStream.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(ip_classification_broadcast.value[0][0]))`

ERROR
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mapValues'

Comment: CASE3:
`ip_classification_rdd = sc.parallelize([('log_name','enrichment_success')])`
joinedStream = kafkaStream.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.join(ip_classification_broadcast))

COMPILES BUT NO OUTPUT on print